# getting error on running the angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

After using ng update to update from 6.1.7 to 8.1.0 i am not longer able to build the project. it gives me

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser
```

i tried

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

i cloned many times but every time when i install node modules and serve the application it gives me sae error

i also tried many many times to uninstall and then nstall the node modules

Answer (score 0):

you only have updated the devkit package but their are other dependent packages which you have to migrate from 6.x.x to 8.x.x.
also you have to replace few lines of code(if written) because of some breaking changes in new version (e.g httpModule to httpClientModule and syntax for child routing & more).

please follow the guide to migrate your project
[angular migration](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: i cloned a project which was already in angular8 but my cli and node and angular was old i updated them

now my versions are:

Angular CLI: 8.3.19

Node: 12.13.1

Angular: 7.2.15

Comment: project environment can be different from global environment. so if you have cloned a project with "package.json" file it will run fine after npm installation.               for more help provide source code link